# Using dash in Web API parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have a Web API method with lots of parameters. The parameters are used to lookup objects in the database. In one case, one of the parameter values has a dash in it (i.e. `http://localhost/api/event/getdata/param-one/2/3/4/`)
I've seen other questions and solutions on here about handling dashes in the controller or action, or even parameter name, but not parameter value. I can't predict all the values, so I need to be able to handle any parameter here with a dash in it.

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
[Route("GetData/{arg0:alpha}/{arg1:int}/{arg2:int}/{arg3:int}/")]
public async Task<Dictionary<string, object>> GetData(string arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened because of the alpha constraint on that first parameter, which only allows alphabetic characters. Changing it to something like `{arg0:length(1,50)}` solved the issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2